# Is it possible to implement Firebase + Auth0 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, auth0

I was wondering if it is possible to do this with Flutter. If someone did it, please guide me a little and thank you very much.

Edit: I need to use Firebase to login (username and password) and use Auth0 (this returns information to Firebase). This article explains why to use it: https://auth0.com/blog/developing-real-time-apps-with-firebase-and-firestore/#Setting-Up-Auth0

Comment: There is a package called FlutterFire that makes using firebase with Flutter extremely useful, and their docs are very easy to follow. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.